# android contact picker with checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox, contacts

i'm using the default way to call the contact picker.

```
public void showContactPicker(View view)
{
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(newIntent, 1);
}
```

but i need to select multiple contacts using checkboxes. how can i put checkboxes in the contacts list? is there a method that i can override that can add checkboxes and get the selected contact ids? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as what I know... You have to make your own Activity class and an adapter class extending simplecursoradapter. You have to make your own xml layout for each row.. and there you can create checkbox for each row so that you can select multiple contacts from your list.